# Injecting a parent's class instance into a module exported function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

This might be a very bad idea, which might explain why I don't see examples of this. My example involves express and websocket, but it really is a basic javascript question, under Node.js.

My top level app creates a custom websocket server class instance, and also calls express routes:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const wss = new MyCustomWsServer();

app.use('/example', example);
...
```

My `example` module implements a classic express route:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/',
  (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('ok!');
    res.status(200).end();
    return next();
  });

module.exports = router;
```

I would like to be able to pass a reference to my `wss` instance to the  `example` route module, doing something like this:

```
app.use('/example', example(wss));
```

The goal being to be able to use that wss instance inside my route, where the console logs 'ok'...

The question is definitely NOT about how to use routes, ws etc... I will eventually have my ws handled by another server instance, pass messages to it through a redis queue etc...

This is just a quick hack, but I couldn't figure it out (learning js). The goal is to give access to that wss instance to different route modules.

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're asking--if you want to call a function and pass a param then do so--if that function happens to call `router.get` that's not really relevant.

Comment: @Dave Newton I don't seen how to hook up that parameter inside the 'example' module. What that module exports is express.Router(), which obviously won't want my extra parameter. That method returns a router object instance, so I suppose I can't simply extend it?

Comment: ... `const buildRouter = server => { router.get('/', (...) => { etc. server.fooBar etc. }); return router; }; module.exports = buildRouter` then call it w/ the server `app.use('/example', buildRouter(wss))` (roughly)

Comment: @Dave Newton Perfect, I just didn't see how to wrap all this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roughly speaking you can always create a function that takes an arbitrary parameter and does something with it, because [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

In this case it *sounds* like you want something (very roughly) like this:

**app.js**

```js
import example from './example'

const wss = new MyCustomWsServer()

app.use('/example', example(wss))
```

**example.js**

```js
const express = require('express')
const router  = express.Router()

const example = wsServer => {
  router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    // Do whatever you want with wsServer here.
  })

  return router
}

export default example
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Will59 Of course :) JS is surprisingly malleable (a double-edged sword). Stuff like this happens all the time around the ecosystem; it's a good pattern to keep in mind (there are other ways to do similar things, of course).